# Apply style for selected value of select on the initial render

Tags: html, css

I would like to make second option have style as `option:checked` when user first time clicks on select to open it. Currently only when user hovers on one of options, necessary style for selected option is applied. It doesn't work in Chrome.

```css
option:checked {
  background-color: #216ba5;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option selected value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following code will make the start(selected) value change css. This can be done with any attribute on an HTML element.

```
option[selected] {
  background-color: #216ba5;
  color: #fff;
}
```